# Does an <img> tag respond to all Http 4XX errors the same as 404s?

Tags: image, http, http-error

EDIT: In an attempt to clarify my question, here's what I'm trying to understand.

If a web page embeds an image like so:

```
`<img src="...">`
```

**How do browser handle receiving different HTTP error status codes from the image url? Is it very consistent across browser, and basically treated the same as if the image wasn't there (404) ?**

Note that I'm aware that I can "just try it", but I don't have every browser/os/phone around to try it out on, and I'd like to understand how this actually works in reasonably modern desktop and mobile browsers (~IE9 and newer as a fuzzy line). Plus if anyone else is every wondering the same thing, they could come here and see the answer too ;-)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm implementing a REST service that returns images and videos securely for a client.

I was thinking it'd be nice to send out different HTTP response codes for different types of failures:

- 400 for general errors (bad request)
- 401 if the user isn't authorized to see the image
- 403 if the user isn't allowed to see the image (forbidden)
- 404 if the image isn't found

Will responding with these different error codes work exactly the same as a 404 response for all reasonably modern browsers from both an HTML and Javascript perspective?

I know the error code would be different of course, but what I'm trying to ensure is that ***no strange security errors*** pop up as a result of using these different HTTP responses.

Comment: Try it? A 401 with the proper headers will show an authentication popup, regardless how the resource is accessed (direct, img tag, script tag)..

Comment: Good point! So I'll ignore 401's then, and send 400s or 403s instead.... How about the other Http codes... any other weird issues with them?

Comment: I'll have to repeat my "try it". ;-) You could read the HTTP RFCs, but browsers can have their own quirks.

Comment: and that's the reason I ask here - RFCs only get you so far... I'm asking if others have gone down this road and realized browser A has quirk B running on os X ;-) and if they do say so, then I can check that scenario myself and see if it really is a problem, and it'd be documented here for others to find instead of having to try it themselves ;-)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The http protocol doesn't know what it is sending/receiving. The error codes are not bounded to the shipped content. It is up to the browser to handle these errors accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 403 is given by lots of public APIs, for example, Amazon's S3 service responds with a 403 when an object with a temporary access time expires.

e.g. An url like so would generate a 403 with the following response (Note: the below isn't a valid S3 url... keys/signature have been changed)

https://somebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test/4a828d8cf5633ab41e2fb8deba599178.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=ACIAICGLRMBL2PTLALHQ&Expires=1424782953&Signature=sWko4DDDRaBS151iEhEZzfDRbU%3D

```
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<Expires>2015-02-24T13:02:33Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2015-02-24T13:02:55Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>F4949A0376EC9DCD</RequestId>
<HostId>
BV8KMzUcmymBUWctoB8mzFAhzcCAMil/F3NXP/KyKxJd/Hun6O2lUh4b0BsVcP9iwjL1sJxreug=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Still note quite an answer to my question - i want to know what different status's are well supported by browsers, but it appears that maybe the answer is all of them. At least this proves/shows an api sending a 403. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using REST I assume you're using Ajax or Angular to request your images, right? 
In that case it is up to javascript  to catch the errors. So, your browser will not show any popups when javascript handles it correctly. 
You could start with something like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
      401: function(err){
        console.log('Login Failed.', err.responseJSON);
        // or whatever...
      }
    }
  });
```

Note, the 401error can be found in the header of the response, and replaces the 'Content-Type: image/png' header. So the Client (browser) has no way to know that is an image was requested and handles it like any other page.